# How to read .gif image file in matlab ? I am reading it with imread command but it is not showing the same color image which is the original

Tags: matlab

The original image is having color but after reading in matlan it is showing gray sacle image and no feature is visible clearly.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? (Code + image)

Comment: May be the colors are stored separately as a colormap.

Comment: Or if not the original image, then the output of `imfinfo`, particularly `ColorType`, would be of use.

Comment: Most likely you are getting an indexed image.

Comment: @Daniel 'd1=imread('8-5-1986.gif',idx);
imshow(d1); ''

Comment: @ ander yes the same with 0 to 255 values.

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant code AND data.